# "The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping" in Windows during composer install laravel

Tags: php, composer-php

so I'm downloading laravel on windows through composer and it is giving me the following error
" Failed to download symfony/process from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping."
I googled a bit and most of the answers were to use the command
" sudo apt-get install zip unzip php-zip ".
But I'm using windows and I can't find any answer relating to the issue.

Comment: are you using wamp ? or xamp ? or laragon ?

Comment: I'm using local server

Comment: then lookup how to install php-zip extention manually to fix your issue

Comment: Have you tried ensuring that you have a line like this in php.ini: `extension=php_zip.dll` ?

Comment: Hello, facing the same problem here.
@LajosArpad in my case the line in the php.ini file is listed as extension=php_zip.dll without the comment (;) 
Solutions that I have found online include [this](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/solved-the-zip-extension-and-unzip-commands-are-both-missing-phpexample.html). The problem is that none of the solutions offer a Windows installation method. All of them are answered basing on linux based systems

Comment: @N69S all the methods online are for Linux based systems. None of them offer solutions for Windows machine

Comment: The system I am using is XAMPP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I enable PHP Extension intl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869521/how-can-i-enable-php-extension-intl)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP error: "The zip extension and unzip command are both missing, skipping."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274829/php-error-the-zip-extension-and-unzip-command-are-both-missing-skipping)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Had the same problem too (Windows). Fixed it by;

Open the php.ini file and uncomment `;extension=zip` to `extension=zip`

Comment: Just ended my month of frustration. Big cheers mate.

Answer (score 8):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php#zip.installation.new.windows:

As of PHP 8.2.0, php_zip.dll DLL must be enabled in php.ini. Previously, this extension was built-in.

Comment: Also for PHP 8.1 i think

Answer (score 4):

**So**, there are three ways to solve this problem

1. As mentioned by @cmb and @OBrienEvance.
2. Second is to use 'git bash' that has unzip command.
3. Third approach would be to install 7zip or any another archiver.

Here is how if you are on latest windows 10 or windows 11.

In PowerShell

> winget install 7zip.7zip

Set its folder as environment variable after this you can use 7z command in PowerShell or in any other terminal.

Comment: The third way works - the system needs to have zip (or similar) installed. In ubuntu `sudo apt install zip` solved this for me.

Comment: Yes as i said any archiver will work system just need  zip or 7zip command. It's strange in your case as most linux distro come with zip installed might be you uninstalled it some point in time easy solution though is just un comment  ;zip in php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

Running `winget install 7zip.7zip` worked for me.

I'm using windows 10 and had problems with the composer global require laravel/installer,
so what I ran `winget install 7zip.7zip` in the Windows PowerShell and it started installing and generating autoload files.

Comment: "This works for me" - what does that mean? Installing 7zip has been recommended multiple times, please do not post duplicated answers

Comment: it means its works on Windows 10 and uncomment php.ini file to  ;extension=zip to extension=zip doesn't work . then what's your problem with that

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it