# The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping. The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\php-8.2.7\php.ini

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2

I'm now using Composer to Install Magento 2.4.6-p1, but I cannot continue.
I have inputed "composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.6-p1 magento2", and inputted username and password, then input "Y" for "Do you want to store credentials for repo.magento.com in C:/Users/zhf/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json".
Then it returned me with the error information:
The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\php-8.2.7\php.ini
I searched in Google, however didn't find way to resolve it.
Please note that I installed PHP.exe in my C disk, and installed XAMPP in my F Disk (I want to install Magento on my local environment).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoJdr.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping" in Windows during composer install laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75050370/the-zip-extension-and-unzip-7z-commands-are-both-missing-skipping-in-windows)