# I have issue about installing laravel using command

Tags: laravel, zip

I am having problems with the installation. I did Composer installation `C:/wamp/www` directory for calcined and create a name:

```bash
composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

I have run and I get the following error

> Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
> The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp2\php\php.ini
> Now trying to download from source

I'm using windows 10

Comment: Well... the error is self-explanatory, you do not have the `zip` extension... you literally have what to do in the error...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping" in Windows during composer install laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75050370/the-zip-extension-and-unzip-7z-commands-are-both-missing-skipping-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

1. go to `php.ini` of your wamp.
2. find `zip` in file.
3. remove semicolon `;` from beginning of the line.
4. reset your `wamp`.
5. good luck